# Elasticsearch Spring JSONObject["hits"] not found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I'm trying to do full text query search on
if i GET http://localhost:8080/search/query/tes
it should show users include tes in first or last name. i implemented them. but something is wrong, it says hits not found (JSONObject["hits"] not found).
Spring Boot with Elasticsearch

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
@Service
public class SearchService implements ISearchService {

@Value("${api.elasticsearch.uri}")
private String elasticSearchUri;

@Value("${api.elasticsearch.search}")
private String elasticSearchSearchPrefix;

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SearchService.class);

@Override
public ResultQuery searchFromQuery(String query) throws IOException {
    String body = HelperFunctions.buildMultiIndexMatchBody(query);
    return executeHttpRequest(body);
}

/**
 * Fetch resultQuery from elastic engine for the given body
 *
 * @param body String
 * @return ResultQuery
 * @throws IOException IOException
 */
private ResultQuery executeHttpRequest(String body) throws IOException{
    try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
        ResultQuery resultQuery = new ResultQuery();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(HelperFunctions.buildSearchUri(elasticSearchUri
                , "", elasticSearchSearchPrefix));
        httpPost.setHeader(Accept, application/json);
        httpPost.setHeader(Content-type, application/json);
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(body, UTF-8));
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            String message = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject(message);
            if(myObject.getJSONObject(hits)
                    .getInt(total) != 0){
                resultQuery
                        .setElements(myObject
                                .getJSONObject(hits)
                                .getJSONArray(hits)
                                .toString());
                resultQuery
                        .setNumberOfResults(myObject.getJSONObject(hits)
                                .getInt(total));
                resultQuery.setTimeTook((float) ((double) myObject.getInt(took) / 1000));
            } else {
                resultQuery.setElements(null);
                resultQuery.setNumberOfResults(0);
                resultQuery.setTimeTook((float) ((double) myObject.getInt(took) / 1000));
            }
        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error while connecting to elastic engine --> {}", e.getMessage());
            resultQuery.setNumberOfResults(0);
        }

        return resultQuery;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: can you see the exception on the elasticsearch server log?

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja checked logs but couldnt see anything related with this.
netbeans output: 2020-07-24 10:45:42.938 ERROR 27664 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.e.s.service.impl.SearchService         : Error while connecting to elastic engine --> JSONObject["hits"] not found.

Comment: can you print search JSON generated from ur code?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WViIm.png

Comment: https://justpaste.it/2yk96 @OpsterElasticsearchNinja

Comment: I see both `".security-7` and `user` index are they part of same search response?

Comment: i sent all _search
here is user/_search: https://justpaste.it/69n3q

Comment: I dont see any issue in ES response, better to add debug and see what is being return from ES and you are converting response to proper JSON

Comment: stucked here :(

Comment: someone help pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was authentication problem. I had created a service on start to connect basicauth (user:pass) but some reason it doesn't have header on that json REST page. So i added token header, voilà it works.